# How to figure out where script is coming from

Tags: javascript, debugging, console

If I have an element that on click starts a script, how do I figure out where the script is coming from? (the source code of the js, the file that holds the function). There is no event like onclick, and there is no jq that handles more, WayneR, so I guess it is coming from a js function somewhere but there are too many and I wish to learn this for the future.

```
    <a href="#Robinson" class="more" id="WayneR">
<div class="more-text-style">More</div>
<img width="21" height="21" src="http://war-mobile.h2client.com/wp-content/plugins/get-all-users/images/bios-more-btn.png">
</a>
```

So I guess something from the developer console...

Answer (score 0):

You are correct!  Something from the developer console indeed!

```
console.dir($('#WayneR').data('events'));
```

If that is entered into either the Firefox or Webkit console (and jQuery is present) it will tell you the events bound to the particular element.

In addition, the other option is to use the console to manually search the Javascript files for #WayneR and see if you can find a binding.

Answer (score 0):

'save' the page with all associated files (in Chrome or FF, not sure how IE lets you do that) and search the files for the function you need. At least that would get you started.